# Unable to click a webelement using selendroid . But Selendroid is able to identify that the Ui Element exists

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, selendroid

*Selendroid is unable to click on a UI Element in WebView, but is able to identify the web element.*

## Following is the stack trace . Please help.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: CATCH_ALL:  
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "{"message":"Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: \"default-src 'self'\".\n"}" 
at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138) 
at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)
```

Comment: The native view is working fine . But is seen only in the web view after recent changes on the server . In the earlier builds the same action would work

Answer (score 1):

If you add 'unsafe-eval' to the Content-security-Policy header of the .html file, you can interact with the element.
It is because of the security settings!

Comment: This response should be a comment since it is not an actual answer to their question